# Using Windows SDK Bootstrapper Packages with WiX

Tags: .net-4.0, crystal-reports, wix, bootstrapper

In tracking down another issue I came across the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages that looks like it contains a number of pre-made installer items for various programs.  I have a project I am on now that requires Crystal Reports and would like to know:

1) Can I use the "Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0" installer project found in this directory to install Crystal Reports using a WiX bootstrapper (exe output) or WiX project (msi output)?

2) How would I go about including this Crystal Reports installation package in the bootstrapper or msi project?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use pretty much any msi/exe setup into bootstrapper

2) If you want to include EXE/MSI into bootstrapper then have a look at the documentation http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/packagegroup.html and i believe what you need is MsiPackage Element for .msi or if it's exe setup then you use ExePackage Element.

Comment: The product.xml of a bootstrapper package in the windows SDK typically contains detection and decision logic, which would need to be reimplemented in WiX and retested.